# Menu MDL not working in templates angularJs

Tags: angularjs, material-design-lite

Please look at the two link's below:

[Example Success](http://plnkr.co/edit/mCQDsAlrz2HfuV9N3K19?p=preview)

[Example Failed](http://plnkr.co/edit/0DlkPBiru0F0SFnETCL4?p=preview)

Note that one of the link's does not display the menu icon.I need help to know what need to load the Material Design Lite to initialize the application.

Comment: resolved http://plnkr.co/edit/0DlkPBiru0F0SFnETCL4?p=preview